# How to remove the bottom margin of page using CSS

Tags: php, html, css

Please see this page:

http://artezanatostudio.com/index.php

Notice that at the bottom there is a margin below the footer bottom line. Thus far, all my efforts to get rid of it have failed. I have attempted to use:

```
body, html { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#footer { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

I even tried:

```
#footer { margin: -50px; }
```

All to no avail.

While the page has many CSS files, the two important ones that I am editing to try to remove the bottom space are the following

site_above/includes/templates/zenn/css/style.css

and

site_above/includes/templates/zenn/css/style-ci.css

If you can provide any clues to assist me it would prevent me from going bold prematurely and you will have the satisfaction that you helped someone who was going mad.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the margin is coming from your .row div

Answer (score 7):

```
    #footer > div.row {
       margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
```

Comment: 7+ answers, and you're the only one who answered the question properly.

Comment: Some people might have not noticed what happens to the header if they remove the margin from `div.row`completely, I guess ^_^

Answer (score 0):

The style sheet the issue is coming from is style-ci.css and the speciifc rule is on the .row div.

Remove:

```
div.row{
    margin-bottom: 26px;
}
```

and make it margin-bottom: 0px;

Note: this is really easy to figure out using Chrome dev tools!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div.row {
font-family: MuseoSans-Reg, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color: #7f7f7f;
margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

They key here is that `margin-bottom` was changed to `0px`.

Do you use a browser with a decent web inspector? I was able to pinpoint it in under 10 seconds using the Chrome web developer console.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there could be a better solution, but for the moment you could try:

```
#footer {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your footer there is a div with class row. It has a margin-bottom with 26px. Remove this value and your issue is fixed.

```
div.row {
   font-family: MuseoSans-Reg, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
   color: #7f7f7f;
}
```

You could also set it to zero but if it's not necessary I suggest you to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `margin-bottom: 26px;` from  **Style-ci.css (line no: 86)**

ie change your `div.row` css as follows

```
div.row {
       font-family: MuseoSans-Reg, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
       color: #7f7f7f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On your `<div class="row">` inside your `<div id="footer">` remove that `margin-bottom: 26px;`

Answer (score 0):

You are able to see this very easily by yourself.

If you are using Mozilla Firefox/Chrome:

1. Right click on the element that you have issue with
2. Select the last option - **Inspect element** (or something similar to it)
3. Start hovering over the elements in the code that popped up to see what makes the additional space appear there!

As you go trough the relevant css styles that appear on right side, you will soon find out where is some **additional margin**.

Which is in this case as everyone already mentioned in the element `div.row`:

```
div.row {
    font-family: MuseoSans-Reg,Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
    color: #7F7F7F;
    margin-bottom: 26px;
}
```

Hope it helped a little!